# R shiny conditionalPanel from Multiple selectInput

Tags: r, shiny

In my shiny app I have a selectInput with multiple=True. This allows to select several variables from a list. 
I would like to add conditionalPanel for every variables of the list which will be display only when the variable is selected.

Exemple :

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

    sidebarPanel(     
      selectInput("variables", "Choose  variables" , choices = c("VAR1", "VAR2", "VAR3", "VAR4"), multiple=TRUE),

      conditionalPanel( 
        condition = " input.variables == 'VAR1' ",
        selectInput("VAR1", "values", c("A", "B", "C"))
        )   
    ),
    mainPanel(
      )
    )
```

The problem is since I choose several variables my condition input$variables == 'VAR1' is false because input.variables contains several values. What condition would work here ? In R the condition would be : "VAR1" %in% input.variables

Thank you

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example. The server is missing.

Answer (score 5):

The Javascript condition you're looking for is

```
input.variables.indexOf('VAR1') > -1
```

Comment: it works great on my end.

Comment: If you use modules or otherwise find yourself with a `variables` object with a hyphen, you can use `input['mymod-variables'].indexOf('VAR1') > -1`

Answer (score 1):

You can make multiple conditions using the `||` so the code looks like:

```
conditionalPanel(
         condition = c("input$variables == 'VAR1' || input$variables == 'VAR2'"),
#here your follwing selectinput
```

That means if your input is VAR1 or its VAR2 or both, the conditional panel accept and it goes to the selectinput. also you can use && to make VAR1 and VAR2 etc.

Also if you want to make one conditionalpanel for each variable, don't use multiple = TRUE, and change to a single choice selectinput.

Comment: Thank you for anwer. I want a different conditionnalPanel for each variable, but I don't want to make a single choice since the aim of this is to print a dataframe with selected variables and with selected conditions. Imagine that I have a dataframe with 200 variables, I want to display in output only 5 of them with some conditions like VAR1 == "A" and VAR4 in ('AAA' ,'BBB'). So I want to display the condition only if the variable is selected above but I cannot have a single selection for every variables.

Answer (score 0):

Join the selected variables into a character string, then do a pattern matching check. This should work

```
selected <- paste(input$variables, collapse=",")
if ("VAR1" %in% selected)
```

Comment: This answer is a bit too terse!

Answer (score 0):

I search this issue also and figure out that the condition must be follow by Javascript.
For anyone also's searching this, Laurent give the correct answer at above.

We can also you the condition below:

```
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.variables.includes('VAR1')")
```